# how to use XPath "for" expression?

Tags: xpath

I have a xml file like this:

```
                <record>
                    <AAA>aaa</AAA>
                    <BBB>bbb</BBB>
                    <CCC>ccc</CCC>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <AAA>ddd</AAA>
                    <BBB>eee</BBB>
                    <CCC>fff</CCC>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <AAA>ggg</AAA>
                    <BBB>hhh</BBB>
                    <CCC>iii</CCC>
                </record>
```

I'd like to get one string that includs all contents in that xml file, something like: "aaa bbb ccc;ddd eee fff;ggg hhh iii;"

How could I implement this with XPath expressions? Maybe with "for in return"?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I don't thing for-in is part of xpath, I'm sure it's part of xquery, which is a different standard (xquery uses xpath).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rarely need to use `for` to iterate over node sequences, because the path operator `/` does the same.

So you can write

```
string-join(record/string-join(*, ' '), ';')
```

Comment: Don't forget the final `;` that the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
string-join((for $r in record return string-join($r/*, ' '), ''), ';')
```

The inner for would generate a sequence of strings, each one being the space-separated string values of the `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` child elements, the `''` adds an empty string to the end of tge sequence, and the outer `string-join` would then join the items of the sequence with semicolons. The extra empty string gives you the trailing semicolon.

Comment: for does not change the context item, you need to write $r/*

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an insight of the possibilities of "for in return":

```
    for $a in //record[1], $b in //record[2], $c in //record[3]
    return concat($a,";",$b,";",$c)
```

I could not add a space between each block of letters, to keep the simplicity of code.

Comment: Using string-join the correct code is: string-join(//record/string-join(*, ' '), ';')

Comment: A final correction: string-join((for $r in //record return string-join($r/*, ' '), ''), ';')

Answer (score 0):

The XML you've provided is not well formed (there is no root element). Providing the record elements are inside of `root` element. Following xpath expression

```
/root/record/*
```

will select elements AAA, BBB, CCC, AAA, BBB, CCC, AAA, BBB, CCC. Then it is up to you to iterate over the result. It obviously depends on language you use, so I can't provide you with an example.

Comment: Actually, the iteration and concatenation can be done in XPath (2.0).